# Paper.js code looks different in Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, paperjs

This is the code for a game where a circle jumps around the page and you need to click it within a certain amount of time ([naomikudren.com/Catch](http://naomikudren.com/Catch/)).

```
var circleSize = 60;
var circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(50, 50), circleSize);
circle.fillColor = "red";
var counter = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var speed = 60;
function onFrame(event) {
    counter2++
    if (counter2 % speed === 0) {
        var newPoint = Point.random() * view.size;
        circle.position = new Point(newPoint, newPoint);
    }
    console.log(counter2)
}
circle.onClick = function(event) {
    var newPoint = Point.random() * view.size;
    circle.position = new Point(newPoint, newPoint);
    this.fillColor = {
        hue: Math.random() * 360,
        saturation: 1,
        brightness: 1,
    };
    counter2 = 0;
    counter++;
    circle.scale(0.99);

    text.content = 'Score ' + counter;
}


var text = new PointText(new Point(50, 50));
text.justification = 'center';
text.fillColor = 'black';
```

That's all fine and dandy, but when I view the Paperscript file as a source in Chrome's developer tools it displays like this:

```
paper._execute = function(__$__,view,Point,Path,PointText,onFrame) {var circleSize = 60;
var circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(50, 50), circleSize);
circle.fillColor = "red";
var counter = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var speed = 60;
function onFrame(event) {
    counter2 = __$__(counter2, "+", 1)
    if (__$__(counter2, "%" , speed) === 0) {
        var newPoint = __$__(Point.random(), "*" , view.size);
        circle.position = new Point(newPoint, newPoint);
    }
    console.log(counter2)
}
circle.onClick = function(event) {
    var newPoint = __$__(Point.random(), "*" , view.size);
    circle.position = new Point(newPoint, newPoint);
    this.fillColor = {
        hue: __$__(Math.random(), "*" , 360),
        saturation: 1,
        brightness: 1,
    };
    counter2 = 0;
    counter = __$__(counter, "+", 1);
    circle.scale(0.99);

    text.content = 'Score ' + counter;
}


var text = new PointText(new Point(50, 50));
text.justification = 'center';
text.fillColor = 'black';

//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiaHR0cDovL25hb21pa3VkcmVuLmNvbS9DYXRjaC9jYXRjaC5qcyIsIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBIiwic291cmNlUm9vdCI6IiIsInNvdXJjZXMiOlsiaHR0cDovL25hb21pa3VkcmVuLmNvbS9DYXRjaC9jYXRjaC5qcyJdfQ==
return { onFrame: onFrame };
}
```

I don't understand what has happened here. Is Chrome not supposed to show the source file as it is? And why is it different than the source file, does this mean that some kind of compilation has happened here from Paperscript to plain JavaScript?

Comment: See my answer below but yes, it means paper has compiled/preprocessed the paperscript file.

Comment: Nice little game, BTW. I'm not fast enough - need to make the browser window smaller... You might want to scale the circle size as some fraction of the canvas size so it is of consistent difficulty regardless of the browser window size.

Comment: That’s cheating! Haha. By the way it was my friend who made that game. Though I will take full credit for getting her into paperjs. [Aronadler.com/asteroid](http://aronadler.com/asteroid/) is all mine though ☺

Comment: If you use any of the native javascript code and find any problems let me know so I can correct the code here.

Comment: Ok will do. Since you're here btw do you know if there is a way to use Paperscript (so with using the vector mathematical operators and not needing to prefix `paper.Path`) within a plain JS file? I like the simplicity of Paperscript but it would be useful to use jQuery in paperjs..

Comment: No, you can't. The preprocessing shows what paper does - it replaces all the operators ("*+%-/") with `__$__(operand, operator, operand)`. The `__$__` function handles the math. You can install the the globals so you don't need to reference `paper.Path`, etc. via `paper.install(window)` - see  http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#install-scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using paperscript, not JavaScript. paperjs preprocesses your code when it is declared as paperscript and what Chrome is showing you is the result of that preprocessing. It makes sense if you think about it - Chrome needs to show you what is being executed in order to debug effectively. It can't be aware of all the transformation different types of script preprocessing might make.

It's one of the reasons that I always use paperjs in JavaScript mode even though 1) the operators don't work, functions have to be used, and 2) `Path.Circle` must be referred to as `paper.Path.Circle` (similar for all other paper objects and variables).

Using paperscript can result in odd behavior in some cases. For example, if you use `view.onFrame = function() {...}` in your code but also declare `function onFrame() {...}` then the view function will be called until your code completes and returns the object `{onFrame: onFrame}` at the end. At that point the onFrame function will replace the `view` handler.

I haven't tested this but here's a quick conversion of your code to native JavaScript. The primary differences are 1) I call `paper.setup` explicitly and 2) all references to paper items are prefixed with `paper.`. I also use the `view.on` handler for frame handling though there are other ways to get that to work.

```
paper.setup("myCanvas");

var circleSize = 60;
var circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new Point(50, 50), circleSize);
circle.fillColor = "red";
var counter = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var speed = 60;

paper.view.on('frame', function(event) {
    counter2++
    if (counter2 % speed === 0) {
        var newPoint = paper.Point.random().multiply(paper.view.size);
        circle.position = new paper.Point(newPoint, newPoint);
    }
    console.log(counter2)    
});

circle.onClick = function(event) {
    var newPoint = paper.Point.random().multiply(paper.view.size);
    circle.position = new paper.Point(newPoint, newPoint);
    this.fillColor = {
        hue: Math.random() * 360,
        saturation: 1,
        brightness: 1,
    };
    counter2 = 0;
    counter++;
    circle.scale(0.99);

    text.content = 'Score ' + counter;
}


var text = new paper.PointText(new paper.Point(50, 50));
text.justification = 'center';
text.fillColor = 'black';
```

Comment: For an discussion on the onFrame handler issue, and other not-to-me obvious aspects of paper's preprocessing this github issue might be of interest: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/810

Comment: Thank you for the third time today @bmacnaughton! :) Your answers are on point. It's nice to see someone else actively involved with paperjs

Comment: I like paper's conceptual model better than any of the other frameworks I've looked at. I haven't toyed with writing any games but I'm getting kind of interested in it now.